New DB Connection Generation at AWS Lambda(node.js) through RDS Proxy
First, I understand that the connection pool with RDS is managed on RDS Proxy.
Therefore, I changed the endpoint toward RDS in the AWS Lambda function to the endpoint of RDS Proxy.
From what I understand, because the connection pool is managed by RDS Proxy, when I use the SHOW PROCESSLIST command in the DB, only the connection information for the corresponding pool should be displayed.
However, when I use the SHOW PROCESSLIST command, the DB Connection appears to be newly created and then disconnected in a short period of time.
The reason it look like the is because the host of the DB Connection is the same as the IP of the DB Proxy.
Belows are the time-dependent result valus for SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST and some values are skipped.
14:28:07



Id
User
Host
db
Command
Time




113246
testadmin
10.0.3.102:23953
testmain
Sleep
0


113247
testadmin
10.0.3.102:33423
testmain
Sleep
0



14:28:12



Id
User
Host
db
Command
Time




113429
testadmin
10.0.3.102:25645
testmain
Sleep
0


113430
testadmin
10.0.3.102:52747
testmain
Sleep
0



14:28:15



Id
User
Host
db
Command
Time




113496
testadmin
10.0.3.102:45863
testmain
Sleep
0


113497
testadmin
10.0.3.102:62891
testmain
Sleep
0


113500
testadmin
10.0.3.102:24823
testmain
Sleep
0


113501
testadmin
10.0.3.102:18577
testmain
Sleep
0



I am curious as to whether the form in which a new process is created on the DB is set correctly.
This is because the number of AbortedClients in AWS Cloudwatch is currently very high.
I'm trying to create a lambda function(node.js) with RDS Proxy as follows:
mysql_proxy_connection.js
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
let mysql_options;

module.exports = {
  init: async () => {
    if(mysql_options) return;

    ... (load the parameters of mysql_options)

    mysql_options = {
      host: process.env.DB_PROXY_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: password,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      connectTimeout: 5000
    };
  },

  // get connection
  getConnection: async () => {
    let mysql_conn;
    try {
      mysql_conn = await mysql.createConnection(mysql_options);
      return mysql_conn;
    } catch (error) {
      if (mysql_conn) {
        await mysql_conn.end();
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

function.js
"use strict";
const mysql = require("../modules/mysql_proxy_connection");
const lambda = require("../modules/invokeLambda");

module.exports.functionLambda = async (event) => {
    // UTC + 9 hours
    const timezone = "9h";

    let response = {};
    let mySqlConn;

    let date = new Date();
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + 9);
    let baseDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");

    try{
      let topic = event['topic'];
      let deviceNo = topic.split('/')[2];
      
      if (event['body']['report_type'] === "event" && event['body']?.['event_type'] === "bootup") {
          
        await mysql.init();
        mySqlConn = await mysql.getConnection();

        let splits = deviceNo.split('-');
        let deviceNumber = splits[1];

        let vms_queryString = ` SELECT * FROM device WHERE device_name = '${deviceNumber}'`;
        let vms_result = await mysql.execQuery(mySqlConn, vms_queryString);

        if(vms_result === undefined || vms_result.length === 0) {
          let errMsg = `${deviceNo} has sent BOOTUP event signal, but there is no device information in VMS`;
          mySqlConn.end();
          throw Error(errMsg);
        }
        
        let fw_version = event['body']?.['boot']?.['fw_version'];
        if ( vms_result[0]['firmware_version'] !== fw_version) {
          let vms_fw_update_queryString = `UPDATE device SET firmware_version = '${fw_version}' WHERE (device_name = '${deviceNumber}')`;          
          await update_firmware(mySqlConn, vms_fw_update_queryString);
        }
      }
      await lambda.invokeLambda(process.env.LAMBDA_CONVERT_DRIVING, JSON.stringify(lambda_invoke_event));

      response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        baseDate
      };
      if(mySqlConn) {
        mySqlConn.end();
      }
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
      response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: err.message
      };
      if(mySqlConn) {
        mySqlConn.end();
      }
      return response;
    }

}

const update_firmware = async (mySqlConn, vms_fw_update_queryString) => {
  try {    
    await mySqlConn.beginTransaction();
    await mysql.execQuery(mySqlConn, vms_fw_update_queryString);
    await mySqlConn.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    await mySqlConn.rollback();
    throw err;
  }
}


handler.js
'use strict';
const function = require("./function");

module.exports.handleFunctionLambda = async (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    try {
        await function.functionLambda(event);
        return callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return callback(null, {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: err
        })
    }
}

Also, the version of node.js is 14.x, and the RDS instance is db.t4g.medium. The mysql version is 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.05.2.
To summarize,

When using RDS Proxy in AWS Lambda(node.js), is it correct for a new process to be created and the deleted like that?
Why is the AbortedClients so high?


Amazon Aurora is not mysql. It is a heavily modified version of mysql with high degree of compatibility on the surface, but very different in its operation. Is the high number of aborted connections causing any performance issues?

Currently, the freeable memory value is low, so I suspect that it is caused by AbortedClients.

And is this causing a performance issue?

Currently, there are no performance issues because it is configured at the stage stage, but there may be problems at the prod stage.

Simulaye the expected workload and you will see if this becomes an issue. Btw, this is a typical symptom of connection pools, but I don't think you use one. Perhaps your proxy uses connection pooling.

That's right, I'm using it by connecting to RDS Proxy Endpoint. Is AbortedClients  increasing due to the Connection Pool typical symptom? To reduce this phenomenon, do I need to get a DB Connection through createPool in Lambda Client?

The other way around: connectiin pools often create connections upfront, so they can give you one quickly to your app. But when a connection pool shuts down, it often forgets to properly close all its connections.

RDS proxy does use connection pooling. I would check out its settings and see if reducing the size of the pool will result in reduction of aborted clients.
